# Pay a wallet address in bitcoin

Tags: transactions

I don't trade in bitcoin, never have and I don't want to continue, but I have a problem I need to pay someone in bit coin, I have their wallet address but I don't know how to go about buying bit coin and paying them. I just need to make this one transaction and that is all. I need to send the equivalent of $351.00 in bit coin. Can anyone help?

Comment: So are you trying to buy bitcoin and then pay them?

Comment: *"a recent report from the CyberEdge Group revealed that only 19% of ransomware victims who pay the ransom actually get their files back."*  - [Forbes.com](https://www.forbes.com/sites/leemathews/2018/03/09/why-you-should-never-pay-a-ransomware-ransom/#31b06f361753)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to buy the bitcoin with fiat (cash) through [localbitcoins.com](http://LocalBitcoins.com) (find a seller with at least a few transactions and 100% reputation). Have the bitcoin fraction you are buying delivered by the seller to the address you want. Just be very sure to get the address correct. You can verify that the funds reached the address by checking on any bitcoin block explorer, such as [blockchain.info](http://BlockChain.info).  Once you verify the bitcoins are the address you want, you can pay the seller.

Comment: You are well to say that you need not act as the intermediate, only the agent to have the Bitcoins directly delivered to the address that must be paid.